# vector(1237) : Assertion failed: "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" && 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, deployment, hololens, hololens-emulator

i am debugging and deploying one Hololens Application on Emulator as well as trying to do so on actual Hololens Device, but i am facing the following exception:

```
_CRT_ASSERT caught:
'''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(1237) : Assertion failed: "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" && 0

'''
Stacktrace:

0x5FEDFAD8 (UnityPlayer) DllGetActivationFactory
0x5FEDF91E (UnityPlayer) DllGetActivationFactory
0x5FEE2F70 (UnityPlayer) DllGetActivationFactory
```

...

i am just doing like:
press play button on visual studio and then it will start its  stuffs for Deployment.

then it will show "Made With Unity" splash Screen and application get crashed.

Comment: We can't help you fix your code if we can't see your code.

Comment: @dávid-florek [you will find code on link](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/assertion-failed-standard-c-libraries-out-of-range-0.475429/)

Comment: Your source code

Answer (score 0):

My project involves procedural meshes and I ran into the same issue today when I tried to deploy to the HoloLens emulator.

If you have a script where a Mesh calls the RecalculateNormals() or similar functions, then try without it. Same issue exists if you assign normals to a mesh.

If you can, please share also the code.

EDIT:

It happens when you deploy it as "Debug", not as "Release".

Comment: Thank you @huzeyfe-sahin

I may need to try for that. it's been long that I had not heard back from customer for any update on that, but appreciate your solution. I will defiantly try it out.